# error in system log - Succeeded authorizing right

Tags: security, mac-osx-server, authorization

Just installed a fresh 10.8.2 server running contacts, DNS, Mail, Open Dir, Profile Manager and Websites. The machine is primerally used for mail which is all fine and as far as i can see there are no problems with postfix.

we are however in the system log getting this repeated error:

```
Jan 14 08:40:10 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:40:10 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
Jan 14 08:40:21 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:40:21 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
Jan 14 08:40:24 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:40:24 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
Jan 14 08:40:25 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:40:25 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
Jan 14 08:40:26 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:40:26 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
Jan 14 08:42:54 server.mydomain.com ARDAgent[375]: Failed to read connect reply.
Jan 14 08:45:06 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:45:06 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
Jan 14 08:45:18 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:45:18 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
Jan 14 08:45:21 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:45:21 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
Jan 14 08:45:24 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:45:24 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
Jan 14 08:47:22 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:47:22 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
Jan 14 08:47:31 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:47:31 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
Jan 14 08:47:32 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:47:32 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
Jan 14 08:47:33 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:47:33 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
Jan 14 08:47:53 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (2,0)
Jan 14 08:47:53 server.mydomain.com com.apple.SecurityServer[19]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.privilege.admin' by client '/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd' [78] for authorization created by '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/ServerEventAgent' [95] (100000,0)
```

Does anyone have any idea what this is related to? searching the net only returns with people who's mail (postfix) is not working?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This likewise has been bothering me as I watch my logs quite a lot due to other development activities.

Answer (score 0):

i too get this but i have noticed a few extra things that might help us get to the most of it.  When i am getting this error, the machine seems to be downloading at about 50k/sec until eventually it writes an entry to the log that reads:

"Jan 20 23:11:03 *server name* AppleFileServer[3278]: Logged out 0x7fe01c024e00"

The data stops downloading at this point.  Usually i would assume that someone has logged into the file server and then logged out, but i had earlier turned all other machines on the network off so the only internal activity should be the server getting and sending mail, or peoples iphones receiving mail.